# how to solve the convex optimiization?

Tags: simulink, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

is that anyone is good in solve this convex optimization problem

[image]

where the v is the virtual reference signal and r is the reference input, at this case we can consider the r(t) as the step input.

For the O_infinity is the Maximal Output Admissible Set (MAS)=〖CA〗^j+〖(C(I-A〗^j)〖(I  - A)〗^(-1) B + D <=s;
where s is the maximum output.

Comment: I believe this is straight forward convex QP. Convex QP solvers are readily available.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen hi are you say about using the command "quadprog'? if yes, I already used and have some error ,you can see the error that show https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029591/how-to-slove-this-error-in-simulink-matrix-dimensions-must-agree  . HJope you can give some feedback to me

Comment: "matrix dimensions must agree" So the obvious thing to do is to check the dimensions.